# How to fix Information Exposure Through Sent Data flaw in Java Web application

Tags: java, security, veracode

I am getting a Veracode `Information Exposure` via `Sent Data` flaw. My code is:

```
String companyName = System.getProperty(EPMIConstants.COMPANY_NAME);
```

This `System.getProperty(EPMIConstants.COMPANY_NAME)` gets its value from a JVM argument hardcoded in the server itself.

The variable `companyName` causes this flaw.

Can someone please tell me how to avoid this flaw?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a rule exception in Veracode so the false positive is not highlighted anymore.

Fabio

Comment: This issue is resolved now. Could you please tell me how to resolve Encapsulation (Trust Boundary Violation) flaw?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/201.html

It looks like this might be a false positive.

Fabio
@fcerullo

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already i have gone through all the theory part related to this. Wherever i searched on internet i got only theory. No practical implementation. Someone please help on this how to resolve this issue.