# Information Exposure Through Sent Data in Java

Tags: java, security

I am getting Information Exposure Through Sent Data flaw from veracode in my Java code. 
Here is my code:

```
// read file and write it into form...
     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

       while (bytesRead > 0) {

          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

            }
```

And the flaw is the line:  `dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);` 
Can someone please help me?

Comment: If i replace it by .write(buffer, 0, bufferSize), it still  shows the same data flaw in veracode.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` instead of `.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize)`.  The `.read` operation may not read `bytesSize` bytes, but instead might read a smaller chunk.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is if the write / read throws an exception - which could show more info than Veracode wants. [Security: CWE-201: What is the correct way to securely read a properties file using openStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758788/security-cwe-201-what-is-the-correct-way-to-securely-read-a-properties-file-us) shows how to wrap IO code - that may help.